# Search for a file inside a tar.gz file without extracting it and copy the result to another folder

Tags: tar

I need to search for a file inside a `tar.gz` file without extracting it. After that, I need to copy the file that was searched (if ever there is) to another folder.

So far I have this, but the copy part of this line gives me an error.

```
gunzip -c file.tar.gz | tar tvf - | grep filename | -exec cp {} /folder/another_folder \;
```

Or is there a better way to search for a file inside a `tar.gz` file without extracting it?

Comment: The problem here is that `-exec` is an option to the `find` command: it's not a command of its own. Also, how are you planning on copying a file from inside the archive without extracting at least that folder?

Comment: so can I change the `grep` to `find` instead so that I can use `-exec`?

Comment: No. `find` is for finding files by name in a directory tree not for searching for a pattern within an input text.

Answer (score 10):

Does your version of `tar` not support the switch `-z`?

```
$ tar ztvf file.tar.gz | grep fliename
```

This would then return the name of the file if it existed at all in the archive.

#### Extracting the file

You could do something like this if you wanted to search for the file first, and only if present then extract it.

```
$ arc="<tarball>"; file="<file to extract>"; \
        tar ztvf $arc | grep $file && tar zxvf $arc $file
```

#### Sample Tarball

```
$ tar ztvf ffmpeg.static.64bit.2013-10-05.tar.gz 
-rwxr-xr-x root/root  19579304 2013-10-05 00:06 ffmpeg
-rwxr-xr-x root/root  19528712 2013-10-05 00:06 ffprobe
```

#### Example

```
$ arc="ffmpeg.static.64bit.2013-10-05.tar.gz"; file="ffmpeg"; \
       tar ztvf $arc | grep $file && tar zxvf $arc $file

-rwxr-xr-x root/root  19579304 2013-10-05 00:06 ffmpeg
ffmpeg
```

*Confirmation*

```
$ ll ffmpeg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manny manny 19579304 Oct  5 00:06 ffmpeg*
```

#### A different directory

If you want to output the extracted file to some other location you can use `tar`'s `-C` switch.

```
$ arc="<tarball>"; file="<file to extract>"; \
        tar ztvf $arc | grep $file && tar zxvf $arc -C /path/to/dir $file
```

#### Example #1

```
$ arc="ffmpeg.static.64bit.2013-10-05.tar.gz"; \
       file="ffmpeg"; tar ztvf $arc | grep $file && tar zxvf $arc -C /tmp $file
```

*Confirmation*

```
$ ll /tmp/ffmpeg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manny manny 19579304 Oct  5 00:06 /tmp/ffmpeg*
```

#### Example #2

```
$ arc=cp210x.tar.gz; file="cp210x/usb-serial/Makefile"; \
       tar ztvf $arc | grep $file && tar zxvf $arc -C /tmp $file
```

*Confirmation*

```
$ ll /tmp/cp210x/usb-serial/Makefile 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 manny manny 388 May 13 01:37 /tmp/cp210x/usb-serial/Makefile
```

#### Example #3

Wildcards could also be used if you want to extract a pattern of files.

```
$ arc=cp210x.tar.gz; file='*Makefile'; \
       tar ztvf $arc | grep -E "$file" && tar zxvf $arc -C /tmp --wildcards "$file"
```

*Confirmation*

```
$ find /tmp/cp210x -ls | grep Makefile
26881948    4 -r--r--r--   1 manny    manny         171 Mar 14  2012 /tmp/cp210x/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/Makefile
26881960    4 -rw-rw-r--   1 manny    manny         388 May 13 01:37 /tmp/cp210x/usb-serial/Makefile
```

#### Details

The above involves a couple of additional changes. We're extracting everything that matches `'*Makefile'`. Notice that we've wrapped it in single quotes vs. double quotes now. This is to protect the `*Makefile` from getting accidentally expanded.

`grep` now includes the switch `-E`, because we're searching for a regular expression now and not just a single string within the output of `tar`. Also the argument to `grep` is also not wrapped in double quotes.

We now use the switch `--wildcards` to the 2nd `tar` so that we can extract based on a pattern rather than just a single file. This argument too is now wrapped in double quotes to protect it.

Comment: When supplying a file name to extract, it must be an exact file name (as found in the archive). So if the file you're looking for is called `foo` and is stored in the archive as `bar/foo`, you need to call `tar xvzf "$arc" bar/foo`. That's why the `-C` option didn't work for me earlier.

Comment: @JosephR. - correct. I'll add an example highlighting that too, thanks.

Comment: @JosephR. - I've added the ability to do a pattern as well. You can use `tar`'s `--wildcards` switch to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in one step, I'm afraid. You can't (easily) extract part of an archive to a different location from the one it's been archived under. You can probably do something like this:

```
pattern=filename
file_path="$(tar tzf file.tar.gz 2>/dev/null| grep "$pattern")"
if [ ! -n "$file_path ];then
    tar xvzf file.tar.gz "$file_path"
    cp "$file_path" /new/location
else
    echo "No files matching $pattern found in archive"
fi
```

Now for that "easily" remark above. The GNU implementation of `tar` has a `--strip-components` option that takes a number and strips that many components from the file name before extraction. So you can count how many components there are before the basename so that you can do a sort of "extract here" operation followed by a copy:

```
pattern=filename
file_path="$(tar tzf file.tar.gz | grep "$pattern" )"
file_name="$(basename "$file_path")"
[ -z "$file_path" ] && echo "No files matching $pattern found." && exit 1
components=0
while [ "$file_path" != '/' ];do
    file_path=$(dirname "$file_path")
    components=$((components+1))
done
tar xvzf file.tar.gz --strip-components "$components" "$file_path" && cp "$file_name" /new/location
```

Comment: You can use the `-C` switch to outout your extracted file to a different location.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. Maybe I'm getting the syntax wrong. Can you show me an example, please?

Comment: The `-C` has to come before the name of the file you're extracting. `tar zxvf $arc -C /dir $file`.

Comment: I think it does a literal `chdir()` to that location, so you have to do it before the files are listed, but just a guess on my part.

Comment: @slm Again, not working.

Comment: @slm I think it only works if you're extracting the whole archive. Besides, it doesn't do an extract here: it still clones the tree inside the archive only starting at a different root.

Comment: I just ran it on Ubuntu 12.10. All my output for my answer is real.

Comment: The dates on the ffmpeg are from the archive, that's a self contained binary build, I just ran those commands and double checked.

Comment: It most definitely works, I just tried it with a file that had a file nested in a directory tree too and that works as well.

Comment: @slm By supplying only the file's basename? Because that gave me a "Not found" error.

Comment: No the full path.

Comment: I assume the /dev/null directory can be change. right?

Comment: @kickass13 `/dev/null` isn't a directory, it's a special file that acts like a black hole for data. I'm using it here to discard the error stream (stderr on file descriptor 2) from the `tar` command in case the file in question doesn't exist. The directory you want to change according to your needs is the one I called `/new/location`.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to search for a file inside a tar.gz file without extracting
>   it. After that, I need to copy the file that was searched (if ever
>   there is) to another folder.
>
> So far I have this, but the copy part of this line gives me an error.
>
> ```
> gunzip -c file.tar.gz | tar tvf - | grep filename | -exec cp {} /folder/another_folder \;
> ```
>
> Or is there a better way to search for a file inside a tar.gz file
>   without extracting it?

A grep-compatible utility that searches tarballs directly is [ugrep](https://github.com/Genivia/ugrep) with option `-z`:

```
-z, --decompress
        Decompress files to search, when compressed.  Archives (.cpio,
        .pax, .tar, and .zip) and compressed archives (e.g. .taz, .tgz,
        .tpz, .tbz, .tbz2, .tb2, .tz2, .tlz, and .txz) are searched and
        matching pathnames of files in archives are output in braces.  If
        -g, -O, -M, or -t is specified, searches files within archives
        whose name matches globs, matches file name extensions, matches
        file signature magic bytes, or matches file types, respectively.
        Supported compression formats: gzip (.gz), compress (.Z), zip,
        bzip2 (requires suffix .bz, .bz2, .bzip2, .tbz, .tbz2, .tb2, .tz2),
        lzma and xz (requires suffix .lzma, .tlz, .xz, .txz).
```

To search for files matching `pattern` in `file.tar.gz` is simply one command:

```
ugrep -z -l "pattern" file.tar.gz
```

To extract the files matching the pattern we can use ugrep with options `-z`, `-l`, and `--format="%s "` to list the matching files in the archive, extracting them to `folder/another_folder`:

```
tar xzf file.tar.gz `ugrep -z -l "pattern" --format="%z " file.tar.gz` -C folder/another_folder
```