# Extract single file from tar to other folder

Tags: scripting, directory, tar, aix

I've searched for multiple forums for this questions and have seen different answers but so far, nothing have worked yet even from the ones I've seen here.

I want to extract a single file from a tar to a different directory.

I've tried this:

```
tar xvf file.tar -C /home/dir/ filename
```

or this:

```
tar -x filename -f file.tar -C /home/dir
```

But got these errors respectively:

```
x filename, 14826 bytes, 29 media blocks.
File -C not present in the archive.
File /home/dir not present in the archive.
```

and:

```
tar: /dev/rmt0: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
```

The first extracted the file but in the same directory, not to the folder I wanted.

Comment: The first works fine for me, what `tar` are you using (`tar --version`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search for a file inside a tar.gz file without extracting it and copy the result to another folder](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96410/search-for-a-file-inside-a-tar-gz-file-without-extracting-it-and-copy-the-result)

Comment: How do I figure out the version of my tar? I tried `tar --version` but it only display the usage

Comment: @slm yeah, I saw that and tried the answers I saw there but nothing works for me.

Comment: @linas31 -what OS are you on? There are different versions of tar.

Comment: The OS I am using is AIX

Comment: @linas31 - that makes a difference. The options from that other answer are for GNU. You'll likely have to use a 2 step approach, unless you have `gtar` installed.

Comment: can I just assign the output of the `tar -x` command to variable?

Comment: @linas31 - what options do you get with a `tar` and nothing else?

Comment: @linas31 If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the check box.

Answer (score 10):

In most versions of `tar`, there are two different modes, depending on whether you put a minus before your options.

The top of the [AIX tar man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds5/tar.htm) summarizes the differences:

```
Berkeley Standards:

tar {c|r|t|u|x} ... [ Archive ] Directory | File ...

X/Open Standards:

tar {-c|-r|-t|-u|-x} ... [-f Archive] ... [-C Directory] File | Directory...
```

Without the minus, `tar` works in Berkeley compatibility mode.  In this mode, the options don't follow now-standard UNIX command line conventions.  Instead, all the flags must be placed together (in any order).  The `f` flag means that the first word after the flags is a file name that should be used instead of the tape drive, `/dev/rmt0`.  (The `t` in `tar` stands for tape, and the defaults reflect this.)  Also note that there is no `-C` option in compatibility mode.

With the minus, `tar` works like most UNIX commands.  All the flags (and their arguments) must be specified first, then the non-flags come after.  `-f` takes a file name as an argument (essentially, the file name belongs to the `-f` flag), so the `file.tar` must come immediately after the `-f`.  That's why the man page says `[-f Archive]` with `Archive` next to the `-f`.  But `-x` takes no arguments (`filename` does not belong to the `-x`).  Again, looking at the man page, `filename` in your example corresponds to `File | Directory...`, which are all the way at the end of the command line.

The fixed versions of your commands look like

```
(cd /home/dir; tar xvf /path/to/file.tar filename)
```

and

```
tar -x -f file.tar -C /home/dir filename
```

GNU tar does something similar.  [The Three Option Styles](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/Styles.html) does a good job of explaining the differences.