# tar with -C not working

Tags: linux, tar

I am trying to un-`tar` into a different directory using this

```
tar xvf BACKUP.tar -C test
```

But I am getting the following errors

```
File -C not present in the archive.
File test not present in the archive.
```

Using

```
tar xv -C test -f BACKUP.tar
```

I get the following error

```
tar: /dev/rmt0: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
```

I do have a test directory and the file BACKUP.tar in the pwd that I am running the tar command in

Still the same error

```
tar -xvf BACKUP.tar -C test
File -C not present in the archive.
File test not present in the archive.
```

And

```
tar --version
```

gives this error

```
tar: Not a recognized flag: -
Usage: tar -{c|r|t|u|x} [ -BdDEFhilmopRUsvwZ ] [ -Number ] [ -f TarFil e ]
           [ -b Blocks ] [ -S [ Feet ] | [ Feet@Density ] | [ Blocksb ] ]
           [ -L InputList ] [-X ExcludeFile] [ -N Blocks ] [ -C Directory ] File ...
Usage: tar {c|r|t|u|x} [ bBdDEfFhilLXmNopRsSUvwZ[0-9] ] ]
           [ Blocks ] [ TarFile ] [ InputList ] [ ExcludeFile ]
           [ [ Feet ] | [ Feet@Density ] | [ Blocksb ] ] [-C Directory ] File ...
```

Comment: check tar with `tar --version` and your platform with `uname -a` Just put that info at the bottom of your post

Comment: Try typing absolute paths, maybe that helps

Comment: From the usage that `tar` spits out it looks like `-C` is supported. You still have not indicated what kind of system this is (or did I miss something?)

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you're on AIX, where you're not allowed to mix old-style options without a minus (`xvf`) and new-style options with a minus (`-C`).

Put a minus in front of all your options, and it should work.

```
tar -xvf BACKUP.tar -C test
```

If that still doesn't work, also put each option separately, as per the help message

```
tar -x -v -f BACKUP.tar -C test
```

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97360/3169

Comment: The post is tagged [tag:linux] by the OP

Comment: "A file or directory in the path name does not exist." is an AIX error message.  On Linux it would say "No such file or directory".  And would default to stdin rather than `/dev/rmt0`.

Comment: I'll take your word for the AIX information. I can't remember, the last time I actually used AIX was around 1989.

Comment: @Anthon still the same error with the minus, is it possible for -C to just not be supported?

Comment: What about `tar -x -v -f BACKUP.tar -C test`?